# Invoke-Expression command is replacing $ if exisiting into string passed

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, cmd

I am executing a ps1 file with one string argument. String argument itself contains $ in it. Which it after combining with certain alphabet it is considering it as a variable.

Description :

```
$variableWithDolar = 'Test$Var'
$inputString = "Testing with " + "`'$variableWithDolar`'" 
$inputString = '"' + $inputString + '"'
$scriptPath="C:\test\PrintArg.ps1"
Invoke-Expression -Command "& `"$scriptPath`" $inputString"
```

Here PrintArg.ps1 is a powershell script that just take an string argument and print it.

Expected Output : "Testing with Test$Var"
Actual Output  :  "Testing with Test"

As it is considering $Var as empty variable.

Can anyone help me how i can I will get my expected output with Invoke-Expression.

Comment: WHY do you use `Invoke-Expression` in the first place?

Comment: @PetSerAl because I need to execute some scripts with these argument

Comment: `& $scriptPath $inputString`. WHY `Invoke-Expression`?

Comment: @PetSerAI Thanks for your feedback. You are correct by that way I can achieve what I am being looking for but since i am making chances in  already existing code I need to understand why instead of this Invoke-Expression is used. Can you also tell any way by which I can achieve this with invoke-expression

Comment: You can just write: `Invoke-Expression '& $scriptPath $inputString'`, but it kind of meaningless. If you really want to embed variable values into string before applying `Invoke-Expression` to it, then you need something like this: `Invoke-Expression "& '$($scriptPath -replace "['‘’‚‛]", '$&$&')' '$($inputString -replace "['‘’‚‛]", '$&$&')'"`. In PowerShell v5 you can use `[System.Management.Automation.Language.CodeGeneration]::EscapeSingleQuotedStringContent` instead of `-replace`.

Comment: Thanks for this @PetSerAl . But can you describe what this code snippet is exactly doing specially -replace part with regex.

Comment: My code embed strings as single quote strings, so that nothing is expanded. But, you have to double every single quote character inside string, so that them will be interpreted literally. Doubling single quote characters, it is what `-replace` is doing.

Comment: @petSerAl can you share some link where I can read about double single quoted strings in powershell

Answer (score 1):

One way is to add single quotes to keep Powershell from trying to substitute for $Var.  In double quoted strings, Powershell will perform variable replacement.  Change the double quotes to single quotes on the first line and add single quotes around $inputString on the last line:

```
$variableWithDolar = 'Test$Var'
$inputString = "Testing with " + $variableWithDolar 
$scriptPath="C:\temp\PrintArg.ps1"
Invoke-Expression -Command "& `"$scriptPath`" '$inputString'"
```

Quotes in Poweshell can be tricky, check the documentation for a full explanation: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847740.aspx

Comment: Actually something I missed in question. Its actually already in single quotes. Question is its replacing during Invoke-Expression. I have edited my code can you please look it at now.

Comment: The change required is the single quotes around $inputString in the Invoke-Expression.

Comment: Single quote around $inputString will not even put value of $inputString